Unable to format trino sql query in expected format
I Have a query-
WITH dataset(ns, tid, nid, type) AS ( values ('PQR',  'ITKT20254',  'A','X'),
                                        ('PQR', 'ITKT20223',    'A','X'), 
                                        ('PQR', 'ABCD23456',    'B','X'), 
                                         ('PQR', 'ABCD54321',   'B','X'), 
                                        ('PQR', 'ITKT21111',    'A','X'),
                                        ('PQR', 'ITKT20000',    'A','Y')
                                         )
 select ns,nid, 
    cast(row(tradelist , res1) as row(tid array(varchar),res varchar)) as finalMap 
from
  (select ns,nid,tradelist,res1 
   from (
      select ns,nid,
          array_agg(cast(tid  as varchar)) as tradelist,
          'not include' as  res1 from
          (select ns,nid,tid from  dataset where type='X' )
       
      group by ns, nid 
     union 
      select ns,nid, 
          array_agg(cast(tid  as varchar)) as tradelist,
          'include' as  res1  from
           (select ns,nid, tid from  dataset where type='Y' )
       
      group by ns, nid
    )
   )

Getting the result-
ns      nid      finalMap
PQR     A   {tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=not include}
PQR     A   {tid=[ITKT20000], res=include}
PQR     B   {tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=not include}

Expected output-
ns      nid      finalMap
PQR     A   [{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=not include},{tid=[ITKT20000], res=include}]
PQR     B   [{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=not include}]

I'm trying to modify the query to get above format. but getting errors in array_agg function

Not sure why you have not used my previous answer but for this one try:
select ns, nid,
  transform(array['include', 'not include'] -- "generated" values 
      ,t -> cast(row(tids, t) as row(tid array(varchar), res varchar))) as finalMap
from (select ns,
             nid,
             array_agg(tid) tids
      from dataset
      group by ns, nid);

Since you generate the include/not include pair you can just use transform to generate corresponding rows
Output:



ns
nid
finalMap




PQR
A
[{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=include}, {tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=not include}]


PQR
B
[{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=include}, {tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=not include}]



UPD
Just add grouping and array_agg:
 select ns,nid,
    array_agg(cast(row(tradelist , res1) as row(tid array(varchar),res varchar))) as finalMap
from
  (select ns,nid,tradelist,res1
   from (
      select ns,nid,
          array_agg(cast(tid  as varchar)) as tradelist,
          'not include' as  res1 from
          (select ns,nid,tid from  dataset where type='X' )

      group by ns, nid
     union
      select ns,nid,
          array_agg(cast(tid  as varchar)) as tradelist,
          'include' as  res1  from
           (select ns,nid, tid from  dataset where type='Y' )

      group by ns, nid
    )
   )
group by ns, nid

Output:



ns
nid
finalMap




PQR
A
[{tid=[ITKT20254, ITKT20223, ITKT21111], res=not include}, {tid=[ITKT20000], res=include}]


PQR
B
[{tid=[ABCD23456, ABCD54321], res=not include}]




I'm using union between 2 queries , may require to ass one more query with union and different res. so transform is not working because for one of the res if list of tid's are not present then it coming like this {res=not include}. So we need to aggregare the res

@Prachi your question in no way or form shows that, you are using union on the same queries (with different res's). And my previous answer describes how to achieve what you need.

As a example I given here 2  same queries with union In real case I'm combining 3 different queries with union which is having 3 different res

@Prachi are the queries the same? Number of results is irrelevant here, you can manipulate  the array.

Query is modified

@Prachi added update.

Done . thanks....

@Prachi if answer works for you - feel free to upvote and mark it as accepted one =)
